# pass results from find to a custom bash function?

Tags: bash, function, shell, loops, find

I have a custom bash test function

```
main () {
    list=$1
    for i in ${list}; do
        echo $i
    done
}
```

which I am trying to call as:

```
main `find . -name hello`
```

but it is only echoing the first file passed in the list. The original output of `find . -name hello` is

```
./world1/hello
./world2/hello
./world3/hello
./world4/hello
./world5/hello
./world6/hello
./world7/hello
./world8/hello
```

How can I make sure the whole list is passed?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you should use function? I can see no use here

Comment: The quick and dirty fix in your case would be to replace the $1 in the function by $@

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a proper [Process-Substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) syntax to loop over files, and you *don't* need a function if you are looking to do a certain action on each of the files from `find` output, just do

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r file
do
    echo "$file"
    # Your other actions on "$file" go here
done < <(find . -type f -name "hello")
```

(or) if you are afraid of having special characters in file-names like a space or any of the meta-characters, use the `-print0` option if it is supported (`GNU findutils` package) to separate the files on `\0` de-limiter and read it back with the same de-limiter.

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do
    echo "$file"
    # Your other actions on "$file" go here
done < <(find . -type f -name "hello" -print0)
```

I just simply do *NOT* recommend using function this-way, but you can do something like,

```
function findRead() {   
    while IFS= read -r file
    do
        echo "$file"
        # Your other actions on "$file" go here
     done <<<"$1"    
}

findRead "$(find . -type f -name "hello")"
```

(or) more-simply just do,

```
function findRead() {    
    for file in "$1"
    do
        echo "$file"
    done
}

findRead "$(find . -type f -name "hello")"
```

The key here is to double-quote the `$(..)` command-substitution that returns the output of `find`, to preserve the new-line characters which are then fed to your custom function.

Comment: thanks! i'm not quite sure i'm doing this right, but I tried: main () {
while IFS= read -r file
do
    echo "$file"
    # Your other actions on "$file" go here
done < <( $1 )
}
with the call:
main `find . -type f -name "OUTCAR"` and it didn't work

Comment: @lenzinho: Why are you using the function again? It makes no sense using it that way. Use the exact syntax as I did.

Comment: i am hoping to use a function because I plan to make this call multiple times in the future and want to have the flexibility of invoking different options depending on the situation