# bash: find truncates some paths

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, find

I'm using MacOS 13.0.1 and try to find + loop over `.mov` files to convert them to MP4 using FFMPEG. Many of my path contain spaces and special characters. I found a way of putting things together thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41845612):

```bash
function convert_to_mp4_then_rm() {
    while IFS= read -r -d '' file
    do
        ffmpeg -i "$file" "${file%.mov}.mp4"
    done < <(find /Users/f.weber/Downloads -type f -name "*.mov" -print0)
}
```

This runs but I found a (random?) error: it looks like some of the paths are truncated when they arrive to the `ffmpeg` CLI.

Example to reproduce with a basic content:

```bash
ll Downloads/
total 9472
-rw-r--r--  1 f.weber  staff   2,3M 26 sep 08:56 23-09-26 08-56-50-2538.mov
-rw-r--r--  1 f.weber  staff   2,3M 26 sep 08:56 23-09-26 08-56-50-2539.mov
```

When I call `convert_to_mp4_then_rm` in a terminal, the first MOV file is properly processed then I have the following error from FFMPEG: `/Downloads/23-09-26 08-56-50-2539.mov: No such file or directory`. In some conditions (e.g. when the path is longer) the truncation is more obvious and can occur in the middle of a word.

What is the explanation for this ? How to forward untruncated paths to my function's core ?

Thanks !

Comment: Truncated? Do you mean the `/Users/f.weber` path in the filename is missing?

Comment: MacOS has a pretty old version of bash, I wouldn't be surprised if it has problems with strange characters in strings.

Comment: Try redirecting stderr to a file so you can view a hex dump to see what weird characters are in the filename.

Comment: Try `ffmpeg -nostdin ...`

Comment: See ["While loop stops reading after the first line in Bash"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800225/while-loop-stops-reading-after-the-first-line-in-bash) and [BashFAQ #89: "I'm reading a file line by line and running ssh or ffmpeg, only the first line gets processed!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089) I personally like the BashFAQ solution that passes the file list over file descriptor #3 (similar to cmo's answer on that stackoverflow question).

Comment: Also see [Execute "ffmpeg" command in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21634088/4154375) and the [How to keep other commands from "eating" the input](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001#How_to_keep_other_commands_from_.22eating.22_the_input) section of [BashFAQ/001 (How can I read a file \(data stream, variable\) line-by-line \(and/or field-by-field)?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).